# How to make a cube continiously rotate in y axis in 3d keeping x and z axis constant in wpf?

Tags: wpf, 3d, rotation

How to make a 3d cube continiously rotate in y axis keeping x and z axis constant in wpf??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code inside a `UserControl`:

```
 <Viewport3D x:Name="CubeLogo"
            Height="400" Width="400" OpacityMask="#FF000000">
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="Camara"
                           FarPlaneDistance="20"
                           NearPlaneDistance="1"
                           LookDirection="0,-0.65,-1"
                           UpDirection="0.220607433377356,0.678217480739237,-0.440841362480504"
                           Position="0,1.6,2.6" FieldOfView="40" />
    </Viewport3D.Camera>

    <Viewport3D.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:6"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="LogoRotation3D"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" RepeatBehavior="Forever" x:Name="Animacion"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Viewport3D.Triggers>

    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <Model3DGroup>
                <AmbientLight Color="White"/>

                <GeometryModel3D ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False">
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,4,5 6,7,8 9,10,11 12,13,14 15,16,17 18,19,20 21,22,23 24,25,26 27,28,29 30,31,32 33,34,35 "
                                        Normals="0,0,-1 0,0,-1 0,0,-1 0,0,-1 0,0,-1 0,0,-1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,-1,0 0,-1,0 0,-1,0 0,-1,0 0,-1,0 0,-1,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 1,0,0 0,1,0 0,1,0 0,1,0 0,1,0 0,1,0 0,1,0 -1,0,0 -1,0,0 -1,0,0 -1,0,0 -1,0,0 -1,0,0"
                                        TextureCoordinates="1,1 1,0 0,0 0,0 0,1 1,1 0,1 1,1 1,0 1,0 0,0 0,1 0,1 1,1 1,0 1,0 0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0 0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0 0,1 0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0 0,1 1,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                                        Positions="-0.5,-0.5,-0.5 -0.5,0.5,-0.5 0.5,0.5,-0.5 0.5,0.5,-0.5 0.5,-0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 0.5,-0.5,-0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 0.5,-0.5,-0.5 0.5,0.5,-0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,-0.5 0.5,0.5,-0.5 -0.5,0.5,-0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,-0.5 -0.5,0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,-0.5"/>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                    <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="LogoRotation3D"
                                                     Angle="35"
                                                     Axis="1 1 1"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Transform>

                    <!-- Background color of the cube -->
                    <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                        <DiffuseMaterial Brush="WhiteSmoke"/>
                    </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>

                    <!-- Content of the cube -->
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial>
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <VisualBrush>
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <Image x:Name="Logo" />
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </Model3DGroup>

        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>

</Viewport3D>
```

And then call it like this in another `XAML`:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RotatoryCube"

<local:RotatoryCube x:Name="RotatoryCubeInterface"></local:RotatoryCube>
```

Nothe the `DoubleAnimation` that says how long the rotation will last, and the `From` and `To` angle. Note too the `AxisRotation3D` that says which `Axis` to rotate and which angle.

Comment: @Sonhja...one question.......why isn't there space between 2nd and 3rd element in Geometry3D Triangle indices.......and same goes for 2nd and 3rd position elements in Normals,TextureCoordinates and Positions.Does it hold any kind of special importance??

Comment: Try it, that part is the one I didn't understand at all, sorry... I found this cube on the net :)